# WICPixelFormatGUID = {????????-????-????-????-????????????} gives on debugging

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmapimage, image-formats

I am trying to display on a button click. i have written a code and i am sure it is correct.

On debuging i get the value of WICPixelFormatGUID = {????????-????-????-????-????????????} and  guidPixelFormatSource = {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}. I don't know why i get these strange values??

My code is as follows-

```
   HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler::ConvertBitmapSourceTo32bppHBITMAP(
        IWICBitmapSource * pBitmapSource, 
        IWICImagingFactory * pImagingFactory, 
        HBITMAP * pStream)
//Pay Attention that this function is called from a static function by creating instance of the class (there is no problem in the function call . I have checked the value of the parameters while debugging   and i am sure that its correct)
    {
        IWICBitmapSource *pBitmapSourceConverted = NULL;
        WICPixelFormatGUID guidPixelFormatSource; /the problem here is here on debugging it gives strange value.
        HRESULT hr = pBitmapSource->GetPixelFormat(&guidPixelFormatSource);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (guidPixelFormatSource != GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA))
        {
            IWICFormatConverter *pFormatConverter;
            hr = pImagingFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pFormatConverter);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                             .......And so on....
            }
        }
    }
```

One more  thing is when i run the same code from non-static function it works fine(but my situation is i have to call it on button click event and it is done by DialogProc()function (and it is static function) and i have no more option left so i created the instance of the class and using those instance and   pointer i am calling this ConvertBitmapSourceTo32bppHBITMAP(by passing the parameter using instances which are intialized in contructor).

Any reasons for the strange value on debugging of the two ???

Comment: Value of CC are Microsoft's way of saying "You haven't given this variable a value". Since you are calling GetPixelFormat, if that is successful, it should fill in a value.

Comment: but when i call th esame function from a Non-Static function and then if i try to debuging then it gives guidPixelFormatSource = {6FDDC324-4E03-4BFE-B185-3D77768DC90C} . why when i call the same from static it gives that strange value ?? any idea ??

Comment: Different `pBitmapSource`?

Comment: @ mats ...sorry i couldn't understand  ??

Comment: Are you calling the function with the same `pBitmapSource` value? Whether a function is `static` or not shouldn't change the behaviour inside the function, so it's probably some other difference somewhere.

Comment: yes i am calling with same pBitmapSource Value..Does that creates the problem ??

Comment: No, my guess what that it's a DIFFERENT pBitmapSource. What is the `hr` value?

Comment: @mats hr = S_OK when i call it first time(i mean i have devloped a preview habdler of .png image. for the first time i get the preview of this .png image in preview pane). second time i want this image to appear on preview pane on a button click at the preview pane so what i do is ..I call the this function ConvertBitmapSourceTo32bppHBITMAP() on a button click event by passing the parameter(with the same value). in the first case hr = S_OK and on button cick event it gives Unhandled exception at 0x000007fefeab6400 in prevhost.exe: 0xC0000005:Access violation writing location 0x0000000301b40005

Comment: why it is doing so ?? any ideas ?? i mean hr = -858993460 in the second case with guidPixelFormatSource = {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC} and WICPixelFormatGUID = {????????-????-????-????-????????????}

Comment: If `hr` is not `OK`, then the value in `guidPixelFormatSource` is undefined, which explains why it's the same value as before the call. I expect the crash is because you are using an invalid pointer.

Comment: i have not released the memory of pBitmapSource pointer  after the first preview on preview pane and just after that i click on the button to have preview for second time on button press event and then it gives these strange values(even on passing the  parameter having the same value on function call).. What do you think that it may be responsible for this strange behaviour ??

Comment: Not necessarily the pBitmapSource that is the problem. Unfortunately, without understanding the WHOLE of your code, it's quite hard to say what is wrong, and why.

Comment: hr = -858993460, convert that to hex.  You keep using uninitialized variables.